# Using ZF2 Query to get values from XML document

Tags: php, xml, zend-framework2

I'm trying to get the values of each `<img>` and `<caption>` elements inside the `<item>` elements and store in an array.

Here's my XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<gallery>
    <item>
        <img>/data/images/galeries/mayens/middle/lemontgond.jpg</img>
        <caption><![CDATA[<font color="black" size="12"> Le Mont-Gond</font>]]></caption>
    </item>
    <item>
        <img>/data/images/galeries/mayens/middle/AlpagedeLodze1.jpg</img>
        <caption><![CDATA[<font color="black" size="12">Alpage de Lodze</font>]]></caption>
    </item>
</gallery>
```

I get the contents of the XML file as a string and create my Query object, then try to get the values but it's always null or not quite correct e.g. I get `Le Mont-Gond]]>` which is incorrect as it hasn't correctly removed the CDATA tags.

```
$content = file_get_contents(__THE_XML_FILE_ABOVE__);

$query = new Query($content);

foreach($query->queryXpath('item') as $item) {
    $subXml = $item->ownerDocument->saveXML($item);
    $subItem = new Query($subXml);

    $resultTitle = $subItem->queryXpath('//caption')->current()->nodeValue;
    $resultUrl   = $subItem->queryXpath('//img')->current()->nodeValue;

    var_dump($resultTitle, $resultUrl); die;
}
```

Returns, not sure why it seems to work for caption but not img ?

```
string ' Le Mont-Gond]]>' (length=16)
string '' (length=0)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working with:

```
$query = new Query();
$query->setDocumentXML($content);

foreach($query->queryXpath('item') as $item) {
    $subXml = $item->ownerDocument->saveXML($item);
    $subItem = new Query();
    $subItem->setDocumentXML($subXml);

    $resultTitle = $subItem->queryXpath('caption')->current()->nodeValue;
    $resultUrl   = $subItem->queryXpath('img')->current()->nodeValue;

    var_dump($resultTitle, $resultUrl); die;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
$reader = new \Zend\Config\Reader\Xml();
$data   = $reader->fromFile(__THE_XML_FILE_ABOVE__);

$items = $data['item'];
foreach($items as $item) {
    var_dump(strip_tags($item['caption']), $item['img']);
}
```

Using your provide xml file data, result is -

```
string ' Le Mont-Gond' (length=13)
string '/data/images/galeries/mayens/middle/lemontgond.jpg' (length=50)
string 'Alpage de Lodze' (length=15)
string '/data/images/galeries/mayens/middle/AlpagedeLodze1.jpg' (length=54)
```

I hope it helps. Let us know if this was not the desired result.